# Git best practices when creating multiple test branches

Tags: git, github, merge, version-control

I've recently started using the branching functionality in git for maintaining my github project, and I understand how to create branches, switch between them, and merge them. However, most of the examples I've seen involve creating one non-master branch, then merging the new branch with master if the changes are to be kept. I haven't found examples for having multiple test branches in parallel.

For example, I'm trying to improve my one of my scripts and I have three different mutually exclusive ideas for improvements, so I make [three new branches.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxHmK.png) I test the performance of the different branches, and [decide to keep one.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIlti.png)

Should I then just delete the two branches that I don't want, and then merge the final branch with master? Will the commits from those branches be kept so that I can revisit them if necessary, or will deleting the branches also delete those commits?

I'm the only contributor, so there's no issue with conflicts with other contributors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you delete the other branches, this does not *immediately* delete the commits; but if you leave the commits unreferenced, then they can eventually be deleted.  There is a "garbage collection" process (`gc`) which runs at certain times (or when you ask it to run), and one of its tasks is to clean up "unreachable" objects (such as commits that are neither pointed to be a ref, nor pointed to by parent pointers of other reachable commits).

So if you want to keep the commits for future reference, you may not want to delete the branches.  Or, if you do want to delete the branches - so that they don't show up on "unmerge branch" lists, or something like that - then you can tag the head of each branch and then delete the branch.

Another option would be to merge each "wrong" branch and then revert the merge

```
A -------------- M1 - W1 - M2 - W2 - M3 <--(master)
 \              /         /          /
  x1 -- x2 -- x3         /          /
   \                    /          /
    y1 -- y2 -- y3 -- y4          /
     \                           /
      z1 - x2 - x3 - x4 - x5 - x6
```

In this example, if you had `branch_x` and `branch_y` with solutions you decided not to keep, and `branch_z` with a solution you decided to keep, you could say

```
git checkout master
git merge x
git revert HEAD
git branch -d x
git merge y
git revert HEAD
git branch -d y
git merge z
git branch -d z
```

This would tell git that you've accounted for the changes in all three branches, but only want to keep the changes from `z`.  This ensures the commits remain reachable so they can't be garbage-collected, and it lets you delete the branches.

On the other hand, actually *finding* the old commits, unless you tag them, could be a hassle - and if you're going to tag them so that you can find them later, then it may not make sense to merge them into your `master` where they can clutter history.